# Negative margin-top causes short jump in firefox

Tags: css

following problem: I have a transparent header and an image underneath it that should be shifted -90px to the top. Setting the container with the image to margin-top:-90px works in all browsers (also in firefox). However on the initial loading of the page, it is loading without the -90px, then jumps to the right position (only in firefox).

The jump feels a bit weird.

It is working with setting it to position: relative and top: -90px, but it leaves a 90px gap at the bottom which I don't want.

Any ideas on this?

Comment: Post your code please

Comment: It's because image is not loaded fully and when loads the image then it applies the css, and having such weird behavior, try to use negative margin in the div instead of image...

Comment: This is a good point ^ Giving the container the height of the image will fix it. Or you could stick with the relative option and apply a minus bottom margin of 90px